# Do `Sub` has a pointer?

Tags: vba

Thanks for reading this.

I stumbled upon this question. We all know that `Function` has pointer. Take this one for example:

```
Function TestPrint2(ByVal NameIn As String)
    TestPrint2 = NameIn
End Function
```

We could get pointer of `TestPrint2` by using `VarPtr(TestPrint2("Hello World!"))`

We could write that above code as `Sub`:

```
Sub TestPrint1(ByRef NameOut As String, ByVal NameIn As String)
    NameOut = NameIn
End Sub
```

Thanks for below comments, I have figured it out that sub/functions do  have their own pointer. (Sr I'm not CS-based but finance-based). I used these subs to test:

```
Function GetBaseAdd(lngadd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    GetBaseAdd = lngadd
End Function
```

And this

```
Sub TestGetBaseAdd()
    Debug.Print "Pointer of Sub TestPrint1 " & GetBaseAdd(AddressOf TestPrint1)
    Debug.Print "Pointer of Sub TestPrint2 " & GetBaseAdd(AddressOf TestPrint2)
    Debug.Print "Pointer receiving return from TestPrint2 " & VarPtr(TestPrint2("Hello World!"))
End Sub
```

Comment: You're getting a pointer to the return value of the function, not the function itself. Look into `AddressOf` ;-)

Comment: FWIW, `VarPtr(TestPrint2("Hello World!"))` will give you the memory address of the return value (on the stack if you call it like that), not a function pointer.